# How to read text file from local folder using coffee file system in Contiki OS? using Cooja script editor or Shell?

Tags: contiki, cooja

I have found this code in paper but Im not good in programming with JavaScript.Anyone could explain how to use this code to upload it in mote and then read it?

```
m = sim.getMote(i);
FILEPATH = "/home/user/energy_traces/cfs_file.txt"
int = m.getInterfaces();
fs = m.getFilesystem();
success = fs.insertFile(FILEPATH);
```